# PHP: Creating class properties from within function

Tags: php

I would like to create a class property such as `$user->first_name` from within a function

```
class user {

    public $first_name = 'Bob';

}

$user = new user;

echo $user->first_name; // OK
```

Now to do this from within a function...

```
public function get_user($key) {

    $data = array(); // This would be an array returned from a MySQL query

    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {

      if ($k == $key) {

        return $v;

    }

}

$user = new user;

echo $user->get_user('first_name'); 
// Works, but I'd like the same format as above. IE:
// $user->first_name;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Properties can be created during runtime, but they're public. https://3v4l.org/MM1nC

Comment: The magic method `__get` will help but please, pretty, please, just use encapsulation and a getter!